# Python Pandas Create Data Frame Column from Variable

Tags: python, pandas

I have a variable storing a string timestamp (in Unix time) that I'd like to append to an existing Python Pandas Data Frame as a column. That is, I'd like the column to contain 143 repeats of the single timestamp, because this is the observation count of the data frame. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(4,4))

In [3]: ts = np.datetime64(int('1326706251'), 's')

In [4]: df['repeating'] = ts

In [5]: print df
          0         1         2         3           repeating
0  0.007547  0.909486  0.742417  0.932215 2012-01-16 09:30:51
1  0.287323  0.748129  0.433262  0.323886 2012-01-16 09:30:51
2  0.664347  0.817915  0.933342  0.847160 2012-01-16 09:30:51
3  0.905030  0.638067  0.362654  0.273651 2012-01-16 09:30:51
```